# Doxygen and Objective-C categories

Tags: objective-c, doxygen, categories

Although the latest releases of Doxygen [claim better handling of Objective-C categories](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/changelog.html), it still seems to choke on categories in my source code. I'm wondering if someone has gotten it to document categories properly.

As an example, I have a category on NSString defined as:

```
@interface NSString (CCFExtensions)
```

with an interface file named NSString_CCFExtensions.h and implementation file NSString_CCFExtension.m

Doxygen will reference the file with the superclass; but none of the category methods are documented, despite seemingly valid doxygen syntax.

What is the correct source markup to get Objective-C categories working?

Answer (score 14):

After some regression testing (and a little common sense) the solution:

Let's say I have a category Cat1 on NSObject, for doxygen to parse my category header file, it should look roughly like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

/*! \category NSObject(Cat1) 
    \abstract A category on NSObject
*/

@interface NSObject(Cat1)
    - (void)foo;
@end
```

and the implementation file:

```
#import "NSObject_Cat1.h"

@implementation NSObject(Cat1)

- (void)foo {
    //  do something
}

@end
```

Importantly, place no spaces between the class name and the category name.