# How to configure Doxygen to document Objective-C categories properly

Tags: objective-c, doxygen, categories

Doxygen appears to have idiosyncratic handling of Objective-C categories and I would like to know if others have been able to work around it successfully.  I would like doxygen to document all categories on a class as separate entities, irrespective of whether the base class is documented or not.

If I add doxygen markup to a category on an *undocumented* base class - say NSString, then doxygen lists the category and its methods in the class list as a separate entity.

```
/**
 *   @category NSString(Foo)
 *   @brief A sample category on NSString
 */
 @interface NSString(Foo)
 @end
```

Results in a documented entity NSString(Foo) in the class list.

But, the following example *does not*:

```
/**
 *    @category CCFMyCustomClass(Foo)
 *    @brief A category on a documented base class
 */
@interface CCFMyCustomClass(Foo)
@end
```

Instead, in the latter case, all of the methods on CCFMyCustomClass(Foo) are included in the documentation for CCFMyCustomClass - the base class.

The following, though often cited, don't seem to help with this problem:

- [Doxygen and Objective-C categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042595/doxygen-and-objective-c-categories)
- http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could skip Doxygen and go with [AppleDoc](http://www.gentlebytes.com/home/appledocapp/).

> appledoc is command line tool that helps Objective-C developers generate Apple-like source code documentation from specially formatted source code comments. It's designed to take as readable source code comments as possible for the input and use comments as well as surrounding source code to generate visually appealing documentation in the form of HTML as well as fully indexed and browsable Xcode documentation set. Although there are several tools that can create HTML documentation for Objective-C, all of those know to me fall short in meeting the minimum of goals described below.

It is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc)

Comment: Thanks - AppleDoc looks much more tailored (of course) to ObjC and Cocoa paradigms.  Will have to look at the migration pathway from extensive Doxygen markup.

Comment: Glad my little suggestion was useful. Good luck with the migration.

Comment: Be aware that appledoc requires attribution unlike doxygen.

Comment: @FeloneousCat And that's a problem because…?

Comment: AppleDoc is much less flexible and omits enums and C++ files. I would not recommend migrating to it.

Comment: I totally agree with @IliasKarim. I have used both Doxygen and Appledoc but former is far better. The best part with Doxygen is you can integrate Graphviz to generate dot files.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, though not ideal is to create a group for the category methods, so that at least they are grouped together on the base class documentation page.

So conforming to the second example above:

```
/** @name    CCCFMyCustomClass(Foo)
             Methods defined only in CCFMyCustomClass(Foo) category */
//@{

/**
 *
 * @method someFooMethod
 * @brief  Does some foo things
 * @details First foo, then more foo, etc.
 */
- (void)someFoodMethod;

//@}
```

Apart from that, I've found no other means of separating out categories on a documented base class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to throw in another vote for Appledoc. It's much easier to get good results out of for Objective-C than Doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

I document my classes (in the header files) like:

```
/**
 @interface MyAppDelegate
 @mainpage  The iPhone App

 This is information about my app, and appears in the main HTML page.\n\n

 As with all iOS apps, the main entry point is an App Delegate @see MyAppDelegate
 @defgroup Classes Classes
 @{
 @brief Miscellaneous Classes

 Classes that don't fit in any other category
 @{
*/
/**
 @brief The application's delegate

 A delegate object is instantiated by the main function, so this is effectively the main entry point for the app
 @see MyAppDelegate()
 */
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@end

/** @} */

/** @} */
```

The .m file has an extension category where I have my private extension methods. This looks like:

```
/**
 @category MyAppDelegate(internal)
 @addtogroup Classes
 @{
 */

/**
 @brief Application delegate class extension

 Internal extension for the application delegate
 @see MyAppDelegate
 */
@interface MyAppDelegate()
...
@end

/** @} */

@implementation MyAppDelegate
...
etc
```

I get two html pages - for MyAppDelegate and MyAppDelegate() The first includes a see-also for the second, though the see-also in the second back to the first doesn't work (it looks like there is an issue with @see category(). However the methods are correctly split between the two pages.

I think the key is to only document your methods inside the Objective-C @interface blocks not inside the @implementation blocks. I also use @defgroup and @addtogroup blocks to group together all modules of a certain type (like View Controllers, Models and so on).

I hope this helps someone